# EU national traveling to EU home country with non EU spouse

Tags: spouses

I'm a Portuguese citizen, living and working with my Indian husband in UK. He has a British residence card. He has traveled visa free to other European countries with me. My question is, does he need a visa to travel along with me to Portugal? It's a tourist trip for a week. If yes, is it a free visa?